# How to get dynamically the Range of two non-contiguous filtered criteria with exception of first row, using `UsedRange`?

Tags: excel, vba, autofilter

[image]

As you see on the sample picture, I set autofilter on column **B** and excluded the value `B`.
I need to get the visible range except the first row, with using `UsedRange` and SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible) method.
I tried the below three codes, but it either add additional row or throw an error:

```
Sub Get_Range_of_two_non_contiguous_filtered_criteria_except_First_Row()
 
    Dim ws As Worksheet, rng As Range
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
 
    Set rng = ws.UsedRange.Offset(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    Debug.Print rng.Address                                                  'Addtional Row is added to rng ($A$2:$B$3,$A$6:$B$8)
 
    Set rng = Intersect(ws.Cells, ws.UsedRange.Offset(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible))
    Debug.Print rng.Address                                                  'Addtional Row is added to rng $A$2:$B$3,$A$6:$B$8
 
    Dim crg As Range: Set crg = ws.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    Set crg = crg.Offset(1, 0).Resize(crg.Rows.Count - 1, crg.Columns.Count)    'Error: Application-defined or object-defined error
    Debug.Print crg.Address
 
End Sub
```

This is the only method I found that it works correctly:

```
Dim LastRow As Long
LastRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
Set rng = ws.Range("A2:B" & LastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
Debug.Print rng.Address
```

In Advance, thanks for all your help and comments.

Comment: Is this a question?

Comment: @FunThomas ,yes it's a question

Comment: But you write that your last method works (and it looks good to me), so what's wrong with it?

Comment: @FunThomas , there's no wrong with it, but I have to define explicitly the start and end columns

Comment: Maybe used named ranges to identify the columns? I wouldn't use `UsedRange` anyhow, although it seems that it is finally more reliable now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The next part is wrong:

```
    Dim crg As Range: Set crg = ws.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    Set crg = crg.Offset(1, 0).Resize(crg.Rows.Count - 1, crg.Columns.Count)    'Error: Application-defined or object-defined error
    Debug.Print crg.Address
```

You need to resize the used range BEFORE using `SpecialCells`. A discontinuous range cannot be resized in that way.

The next adapted code should work:

```
    Dim crg As Range: Set crg = ws.UsedRange
    Dim crgVS As Range
     Debug.Print crg.Resize(crg.rows.count - 1, crg.Columns.count).Offset(1).address
    Set crgVS = crg.Resize(crg.rows.count - 1, crg.Columns.count).Offset(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
     Debug.Print crgVS.address
```

And I would (only) suggest you to use `Range("A1").CurrentRegion`. `UsedRange` works well on a virgin/new sheet. It may include the rows/columns you previously used to use them, even if they are empty now. Try coloring the interior or a cell below the existing range and check the `UsedRange` address. And results in such a case may not fulfill your expectations...

Comment: Mr, FaneDuru It works correctly in all cases, even if I used only one criteria in AutoFilter

Comment: @Leedo Not sure I correctly understood what you mean. Are you referring to suggestion of avoiding `UsedRange`?

Comment: The other answer by “Ike” only works on non-discontinues ranges, Meaning If Set filter on only one criteria e.g `value= A`, then
I got error `Application-defined or object-defined error`

Comment: @Leedo Is not only that... Why iterating and extracting rows in a `Union` range when it is possible to do it without, in the way you tried but missing the fact that the discontinuous range cannot be resized in the classic way? It is a working piece of code, anyhow... And, in order to better understand what I meant related to `UsedRange`, color  the interior of a cell below the existing `UsedRange` and then clear it. Run the code and see that now  `UsedRange` has been extended to include it. The filter knows how to act, but `SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)` will include the last blank rows...

Comment: I found out that the output of `crgVS.Rows.count` is wrong, please how to fix it ?

Comment: @Leedo Nothing is wrong. VBA is not able to return the rows count for a discontinuous range! It returns only the first **Area** number of rows... It also is not able to return **its address, neither**, if its address string exceeds 256 characters. You can iterate in such a range only using `For each x in crgVS.Rows`. VBA handles its rows, but is not able to count them...

Comment: @Leedo I meant VBA trunks the discontinuous range address to only 256 (string) digits, if this amount is exceeded.

Answer (score 0):

iterating over the areas works:

```vb
    Dim crg as range, a As Range
    With ws.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
        For Each a In .Areas
            If Not crg Is Nothing Then
                Set crg = Union(crg, a)
            Else
                'this area must include the first row -> remove
                Set crg = a.Offset(1).Resize(a.Rows.Count - 1)
            End If
        Next
    End With
```